# Array lenght and data miss match while storing data of events

Tags: solidity, web3js, javascript, events, react

Can someone help me in finding what is wrong here a why the length of task info is 0 even the taskInfo has some data. I'm using events to fill the taskinfo array.
I'm stuck at this place for almost 2 days and cant seem to find what is wrong here
any kind of help is appreciated[[image: ![]

[image]

Comment: What's the problem? Is it that the logged value of taskInfo is different from the expected length? It doesn't seem related to Ethereum more like a javascript/browser issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is not related to ethereum or web3 as suggested in the comments.
You can look into this for your answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32460602/array-shows-0-as-length-when-it-has-elements-in-it